# C programming function while loop doesn't end after return

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

The code below never stops the loop; it is supposed to stop looping and recursively call the next function like I do with `return`. yet the squares are always looped to the latest edge.

```
int solve(char **map, int x, int y, int n, char obs, int maxIndex) 
{
    while (y <= n)
    {
        while (x <= n)
        {
            if (x == maxIndex) //line bitt
            {
                x = 0;
                y++;
                if (y == maxIndex) {
                    return solve(map, 0, 0, n - 1, obs, maxIndex+1); //y esitse eger maxIndex arttiriyorz ve n dusuyoruz bir sonrakie kare icin. y kondisyonu dogruysa bu kare bitmistir

                } else {
                    return solve(map, x, y, n, obs, maxIndex); 
                }
            } else {
                 if (map[y][x] == obs) {
                    x++;
                    printf("obs found, x=%d y=%d n=%d \n", x, y, n);
                    return solve(map, x, y, n, obs, maxIndex);
                } else {
                    if ((y == maxIndex - 1) && (x == maxIndex - 1)) {
                        printf("square found, x=%d y=%d n=%d\n", x, y, n);
                        //kare bulundu
                    }
                }
            }
            x++;
        }
        y++;
    } 
}
```

Session:

```
10.oX
.o.o.o....
o..oo...o.
.........o
...oo....o
..........
......o..o
....o.....
..........
ooo.......
........oo
OBS= o
square found, x=0 y=0 n=10
obsticle found, x=2 y=0 n=9 
obsticle found, x=1 y=1 n=9 
square found, x=1 y=1 n=9
obsticle found, x=2 y=0 n=8 
obsticle found, x=1 y=1 n=8 
square found, x=2 y=2 n=8
obsticle found, x=2 y=0 n=7 
obsticle found, x=4 y=0 n=7 
obsticle found, x=1 y=1 n=7 
obsticle found, x=4 y=1 n=7 
obsticle found, x=4 y=3 n=7 
obsticle found, x=2 y=0 n=6 
obsticle found, x=4 y=0 n=6 
obsticle found, x=1 y=1 n=6 
obsticle found, x=4 y=1 n=6 
obsticle found, x=5 y=1 n=6 
obsticle found, x=4 y=3 n=6 
obsticle found, x=5 y=3 n=6 
square found, x=4 y=4 n=6
obsticle found, x=2 y=0 n=5 
obsticle found, x=4 y=0 n=5 
obsticle found, x=6 y=0 n=5
```

Yes the `x` and `y` always hits to the edge for that square size `n`,

```
        printf("obs found, x=%d y=%d n=%d \n", x, y, n);
        return solve(map, x, y, n, obs, maxIndex);
```

So with this code above it is supposed to stop looping the current square and recursively call next, since I use `return`. Yet it seems to hit the edge as seens is the output.

What is the problem here?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/205233)

Comment: `for` loop alergy?

Comment: this is an assignment, we are not allowed to use for, please help me find the problem

Comment: @bugra: `for` loops are highly recommended, let's hope your school is teaching you that by making you experiment lesser alternatives.

Comment: edit your question with the full assignment, so we can answer while staying in the specific scope.

Comment: 99% of the time, use a `for` loop. Recursion and `while` aren't necessary often, generally only for very particular cases (logarithmic data structure traversals and repeating something when there is a nondeterminstic stopping condition, respectively). For regular old linear iteration, use `for`.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple problems:

- there is no explicit `return` statement when the outer loop finishes.  You should add `return 0;` or make the function `void`.
- there is no need to recurse with `return solve(map, x, y, n, obs, maxIndex);`  for the next `y`, you could modify the code to avoid this tail recursion.
- the coordinates output by `printf("obs found, x=%d y=%d n=%d \n", x, y, n)` are incorrect as `x` has been incremented already
- assuming `n` is the dimension of the empty square and `maxIndex` the dimensions of the indirect 2D `map`, recursing with `solve(map, x, y, n, obs, maxIndex)` may find squares that are not empty as the erroneous output shows:

  ```
  square found, x=0 y=0 n=10
  square found, x=1 y=1 n=9
  square found, x=2 y=2 n=8
  square found, x=4 y=4 n=6
  ```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int solve(char **map, int n, int min_n, char obs, int maxIndex)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (n >= min_n) {
        int y = 0;
        while (y <= maxIndex - n) {
            int x = 0;
            while (x <= maxIndex - n) {
                int empty = 1;
                int h = 0;
                while (h < n && empty) {
                    int w = 0;
                    while (w < n && empty) {
                        if (map[y + h][x + w] == obs) {
                            empty = 0;
                        }
                        w++;
                    }
                    h++;
                }
                if (empty) {
                    printf("square found, x=%d y=%d n=%d\n", x, y, n);
                    count++;
                }
                x++;
            }
            y++;
        }
        n--;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void) {
    char **map;
    int dim;
    char cc[10], eol[2];

    if (scanf("%d%9s%1[\n]", &dim, cc, eol) != 3)
        return 1;
    map = calloc(dim, sizeof *map);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        map[i] = calloc(dim + 2, sizeof *map[i]);
        if (!fgets(map[i], dim + 2, stdin))
            return 1;
    }
    printf("%d%s\n", dim, cc);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        fputs(map[i], stdout);
    }
    for (int i = 0; cc[i] != '\0' && cc[i] != 'X'; i++) {
        if (cc[i] != '.') {
            printf("OBS=%c\n", cc[i]);
            solve(map, dim, 3, cc[i], dim);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10.oX
.o.o.o....
o..oo...o.
.........o
...oo....o
..........
......o..o
....o.....
..........
ooo.......
........oo
OBS=o
square found, x=0 y=4 n=4
square found, x=5 y=1 n=3
square found, x=0 y=2 n=3
square found, x=5 y=2 n=3
square found, x=6 y=2 n=3
square found, x=0 y=3 n=3
square found, x=0 y=4 n=3
square found, x=1 y=4 n=3
square found, x=0 y=5 n=3
square found, x=1 y=5 n=3
square found, x=5 y=6 n=3
square found, x=6 y=6 n=3
square found, x=7 y=6 n=3
square found, x=3 y=7 n=3
square found, x=4 y=7 n=3
square found, x=5 y=7 n=3
```